# Connecting GKE Kube Master with ssh

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a GKE cluster using teraform scripts as private cluster.

The worker nodes are assigned with private IPs (starting with 9.X.X.X) and I am able to to ssh. However, my kube master has been assigned with (172.X.X.X), I am able to connect through gcloud shell.

How can I connect kube master via terminal using ssh?

Comment: What is the gcloud shell and how do you connect?

Answer (score 1):

In GKE you can not see the master node from the UI. So, you don't know the public IP of the master node. Hence you can not ssh to kube master from your local terminal.

You can get the cluster credential by running:

```
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials ${CLUSTER_NAME}
```

Comment: We can get the master IP address using `kubectl cluster-info` so that part of this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

GKE is a managed service from google cloud platform. The worker nodes that we created will hook-on to the manage service and the worker nodes are managed.

If we install kubernetes on VMs (Manually using the kube yum repo) and join the worker nodes to master, then we will have access to master node through ssh command,

Answer (score 0):

If you cluster is private, you will need to add the host IP addresses that are interested in connecting to the master. Individual IP addresses, like a VPN, or a home IP, should be added as `/32`

[image]